# Can I make type redefinition more optimal?

Tags: go

I have such code:

```
type Speed float64
type Distance float64
type Time float64


func speed(a Distance, b Time) Speed {
    return Speed(float64(a) / float64(b))
}

func main() {
    s := Distance(123.0)
    t := Time(300)
    fmt.Println(speed(s, t))
}
```

Can I make it more optimal by removing somehow casting to float64 in speed function?

Comment: No, but but for something like this I don't think there's a solid reason to not just use float64 if you're not defining any methods.

Comment: Reason is (for me) simple: I want to make sure we are operating on proper type and complier will save me from writing lot of specs.

Comment: This _is_ optimal.

Comment: If you want to use the type system for that, you need to be explicit about the conversions. Note that this still doesn't save you you from calling `speed(123, 300)`, where the conversion is done on assignment, and the types are mostly hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot avoid casting your distance and time back into floats because the division is not defined for those types. And as previously said, Go is strongly typed.

So, in your case you'd have to put casts everywhere (not a good idea). Type aliasing is good if you want to write custom methods for your types, but its purpose is not to solely hide the underlying type under a custom one.

However, not all type are working this way. If you make an alias of a map, then you can call the bracket operators without problem.

```
type Map map[string]string

func main() {
    m := Map(make(map[string]string))
    m["answer"] = "42"
    fmt.Printf("m's type is %T and answer is %s\n", m, m["answer"]) 
    //
    // m's type is main.Map and answer is 42
}
```

Also, when initializing your custom aliases, casting is unnecessary:

```
type Speed float64
type Distance float64

func main() {
    var s Distance = 123.0
    var t Time = 300

    // ...
}
```

This compiles and works perfectly. What happens behind the scene is that the literal `123.0` is considered as an untyped float and `300` is considered as an untyped int.

I know this sounds weird but basically those values are not typed so Go tries to fit them into the type at the left. This is why you can write `var f float64 = 1` even though `1` is not a float. But you can't write `var f float64 = int(1)` because 1 becomes a typed int which cannot be translated in a `float64`.

This is why the following won't work:

```
func main() {
    var distance float64 = 123.0
    var time float64 = 300

    var s Distance = distance
    var t Time = time

    // ...
}
```

Comment: To be precise, there is no "casting" in Go, and conversion on assignment is still type conversion, i.e. `var s Distance = 123.0` is equivalent to `s := Distance(123.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make implicit casts between custom types-- Go is strongly typed.

I know this is just a small example, but maybe you really don't need those custom types?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func speed(distance float64, time float64) float64 {
    return distance / time
}

func main() {
    s := 123.0
    t := 300.0
    fmt.Println(speed(s, t))
}
```